# SQLAlchemy automatically create entry in table "A" when table entry "B" is created

Tags: python, mysql, database-design, sqlalchemy

I think that this solution is straightforward, but I am struggling with it. Maybe I have been staring at it far too long.

Scenario: For simplicity, say my database has a Users, Rundata, and a Timestamps table. See below

```
class User(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column(String(20))
    # ...
    registered_on = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('timestamps.id'))


class DataRecord(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'data_records'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('rundata_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    timestamp_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('timestamps.id'))

    timestamp = relationship('Timestamp')  # one (datarecord) to many (many datarecords from different units will share a timestamp)

    Tank_P        = Column(Float)
    # ...
    Reactor_P     = Column(Float)


class Timestamp(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'timestamps'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('timestamp_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime)

    def __init__(self, timestamp=None):
        if timestamp:
            self.timestamp = timestamp
        else:
            self.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
```

Question 1: Can I build a method into the models so that certain timestamps are created in the timestamps table on creation of a new User? When a User is entered into the db, the registered_on field gets the foreign key of the timestamp that was created. Pseudocode:

```
my_user = User(dict_of_data)
db_session.add(my_user)
db_session.commit()
```

Question 2: When DataRecord entries are created, many different records (corresponding to each unit creating rundata) will be entered at once. Ie, many DataRecord entries will share a timestamp. This timestamp comes from an outside source (unlike the User's registered_on timestamp) Do I need something like the below pseudocode?

```
ts = timestamp_from_data_software  # externally sourced timestamp
my_timestamp = Timestamp(ts)
db_session.add(my_timestamp)
my_timestamp_id = my_timestamp.get_id()
for r in datarecords:
    dr = DataRecord(dict_of_data, timestamp_id=my_timestamp_id)
    db_session.add(dr)
db_session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can do what you are suggesting here. The code that you have presented should work fine as well.

Although, I would strongly recommend you to not use a separate model for `Timestamp`, unless you really have some weird need to do so (Why do you want to use a different model?) You should just use a `datetime` type field called `timestamp` in either of those columns. And of course in that case, each time you create an entry in the tables, you can also enter what ever timestamp you want to.

**Appendix:**

In the second code example of yours though I would do this,

```
ts = timestamp_from_data_software  # externally sourced timestamp
my_timestamp = Timestamp(ts)
db_session.add(my_timestamp)
# my_timestamp_id = my_timestamp.get_id() You don't need to do this
for r in datarecords:
    dr = DataRecord(dict_of_data, timestamp_id=my_timestamp)  # just use my_timestamp
    db_session.add(dr)
db_session.commit()
```

**TL;DR:** It's possible, but **don't** have an extra model for timestamp, just use columns.

Comment: why do you recommend not having an extra `timestamp` model? the system is writing as many as 100 records at a time to the `rundata` table, all with the same timestamp, every couple minutes. My thought was that it would dramatically keep the size down

Comment: 100 is a very small number. You need to consider that each time you make a join, that's heavier than having a column. Also in python level, if its a new model, it takes more space to keep the python object. Also it takes greater amount of time to create an object. Try to do as much as you can in database level, that's faster and more optimized unless you're doing something crazy.

Comment: Its also better to keep the database schema as simple as possible for better code readability and maintenance.